# Calculate two limits

Tags: limits

I have to evaluate the following limits:
$$\lim_{n\to 0} \left( \frac{3^n-2^n}{4^n-3^n}\right)^{1/n}$$
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \left( \frac{3^n-2^n}{4^n-3^n}\right)^{1/n}$$

In the second one I think I can use squeeze theorem, but I have no idea about the first one.

Comment: For the first limit, the expression inside the parentheses is valid for n=0, but it gives zero divided by zero. This is usually an indication that L'Hospital's rule is the way to go.

Comment: @MonkeysUncle: I don't think it's doable with L'Hospital, because then the limit does not exist and one cannot conclude anything about the starting limit.

Comment: After L'Hospital's I would think the inner expression approaches n/3-n/2 divided by n/4-n/3. Is this technically not valid?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: For the first one, rearrange in exponential form:
$$\lim_{n \to 0}\exp\left(\frac1n\ln\left(\frac{3^n - 2^n}{4^n - 3^n}\right)\right)$$
then use MacLaurin expansion to simplify the expression. What happens?

For the second one, observe that, for $n \to +\infty$,
$$\frac{3^n - 2^n}{4^n - 3^n} \sim \frac{3^n}{4^n}$$
Alternatively, just factorize the expression:
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty}\left(\frac{3^n}{4^n}\cdot\frac{1 - \left(\frac23\right)^n}{1 - \left(\frac43\right)^n}\right)^{1/n}$$
and the result follows immediately.

Comment: is there any way of not using power series?

Comment: @lkszww: For the second one, yes. I've added it to my answer.

Comment: And the first one?

Comment: @lkszww: I'll think more about it, but the series expansion approach is really straightforward. If anything comes to my mind, I'll add to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I mean power series werent introduced at my course for now

Answer (score 0):

For the first limit, we have
$$\frac{3^x-2^x}{4^x-3^x}=\frac{\frac{3^x-1}x-\frac{2^x-1}x}{\frac{4^x-1}x-\frac{3^x-1}x}\to \frac{\ln 3-\ln 2}{\ln 4-\ln 3}>0$$
hence
$$\Bigl(\frac{3^x-2^x}{4^x-3^x}\Bigr)^{\frac 1x}=\exp\Bigl(\frac 1x\ln\frac{3^x-2^x}{4^x-3^x}\Bigr)\to +\infty$$
as $x\to 0^+$, while
$$\Bigl(\frac{3^x-2^x}{4^x-3^x}\Bigr)^{\frac 1x}\to 0^+$$
as $x\to 0^-$.

For the second
$$\frac{3^x-2^x}{4^x-3^x}\sim\Bigl(\frac 34\Bigr)^x\to 0$$
and, in particular,
$$\frac{3^x-2^x}{4^x-3^x}=\Bigl(\frac 34\Bigr)^x\frac{1-(\frac 23)^x}{1-(\frac 34)^x}$$
hence
$$\frac 1x\ln \frac{3^x-2^x}{4^x-3^x}=\ln\frac34+\frac 1x\ln\frac{1-(\frac 23)^x}{1-(\frac 34)^x}\to\ln\frac 34$$
and
$$\Bigl(\frac{3^x-2^x}{4^x-3^x}\Bigr)^{\frac 1x}=\exp\Bigl(\frac 1x\ln\frac{3^x-2^x}{4^x-3^x}\Bigr)\to\frac 34$$
as $x\to+\infty$.